# shared variables and parallel.forEach

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel.foreach

I got it a bit strange calculation, it used to take a really long time.
Until i started to use a nested parallel for

```
double[] epochs={0.001,0.003,0.0013,0.04    .... }
double[] variate= {0.001,0.003,0.0013,0.04    .... }
Parallel.ForEach(ep, epochs => 
{
    parallel.foreach(vr ,variate =>
    {
        //heavy calculation..
    }
}
```

During debugging i noticed that sometimes better solutions where skipped

The calculation is about a data set and finding an optimal solution.
Its a lot of code, but in the end it rates itself, and if better it should pass a double[] array back, consisting of a better genetic solution. 
I can then use that solution array for futher parallel.foreach loops to be based upon.

While debugging i've noticed global variables dont work that well with parallel code. 
A (kind of overkill) solution could be to let each thread cal a winsock connection while a socket listener performs an exchange of data between the threads. Maybe easier would be to write to disk, and let each thread watch if they are better as compared to the result on disk, if so overwrite disk file.

This comparing of better is not happening that often (since the calculation takes a long time ~7 minutes or so), so file locks would not be likely.
but it doesnt seam right to miss use file system, or socket protocols for this.
Wouldnt this be possible with some kind of shared memory construction ?

Maybe some static List or maybe a Dictionary (indexed by result score?).
Or is there perhaps another way to do this with parralel.forEach

(I wrote code in c#6 .net 4.6 )

Comment: In the future, please tag the question with the language you're using

Comment: okay added the tag, its c# 4.6

Comment: C# Doesn't have a version 4.6. Did you mean C# 6 with .NET 4.6?

Comment: Oh ah yes, got confused by the various updates to the .net naming (.net core, .net standard. classic.net)  thanks for reminding

Comment: Could you explain how are you using the global variables and how exactly do they not "work well"? Ideally, could you show some code that actually uses that variable?

Comment: The code is too large, essentially hundreds of threads try to solve a problem. for which there are many unknown inputs,  by use of trial and error it solves an answer. Each answer can be written as an array of doubles and score rating. Currently running threads, and new threads should be aware that if a better rating gets available that they should compare against that their latest solution.
What i saw while debuging, is that active threads didnt compare against updated global variables but seam to use the best value as was known when they started, despite they compare in the end